# Em qual(is) camada(s) de um projeto DDD devo implementar um recurso de Importar/Exportar arquivos de texto e relatórios

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Tenho um projeto em C# usando o padrão DDD + EF Core, com base em um projeto muito bom do Eduardo Pires: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject/tree/master/src)

Preciso implementar dois recursos: Importação/Exportação (TXT, CSV, DOC, XLS...) e Relatórios.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Em qual(is) camada(as) eu implemento essas duas funcionalidades? No caso da importação/exportação, será necessário criar funções (semelhante a um repositório EF)... Em qual camada elas ficariam? ... E os relatórios, por exemplo, se eu usasse o Crystal ou outro componente, onde ficariam instalados?

Se alguém tiver algum projeto de exemplo ou tutorias detalhados, que possam me ajudar, agradeço muito, pois já perdi muito tempo garimpando essas informações na net, mas não encontrei nada consistente.

Abraço a todos e muito obrigado!

Comment: Baseado nesse projeto modelo eu criaria algo assim: Infra.Crosscutting.Reports, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, na minha concepção, criaria na camada de Infra, como um serviço,  e tudo que estivesse ligado ao processo desses arquivos usaria lá e colocaria meu código para usa-lo como que usa um serviço de login, acesso ao banco, etc...

Agora se os arquivos fazem parte das entidades, são atributos delas, tentaria criar os arquivos ou relatórios como entidades.